# SharePoint designer 2013 Workflow unable to send email to phone

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

How to send an email(text message) to phone number using SharePoint designer 2013 Workflow? 
1234567890@txt.att.net is working for SharePoint designer 2010 Workflow but not in 2013 Workflow?

Any other workaround would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**As a workaround,** You can trigger a SharePoint 2010 Workflow from SharePoint 2013 workflow by doing the following:

- At your SharePoint 2013 workflow, Instead of adding `Send Email` action, try to add  `Start a List workflow` action to start your SharePoint 2010 Workflow.

[image]

For more details check [How to trigger a SharePoint 2010 workflow from a SharePoint 2013 workflow](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2012/08/17/how-to-trigger-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-from-a-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)

Comment: I have used the "Start a List Workflow" action before to bring in a 2010 workflow and each time the end user with permissions of "Site: Read, List: Contribute" it would cause an "Interop Services error". It works correctly for me (Tenant Admin) each time. When I went to play around with user permissions to see if that was the problem, it would only work for the end user when I elevated their site permissions to "Contribute" which I find to be crazy. Has anyone else ever experienced anything like this? I never did get this to work, so I removed the action.

Comment: App step should help, but you should be aware of you can't use "Start a List Workflow" inside it :(

Comment: Yes, I read a little bit about that. But is that normal that I would have to do that?